# c#: inheritance and abstract classes - base. vs :base (in constructor initializers)

Tags: c#, inheritance, constructor, abstract

I'm getting an error: "The type Book' does not contain a constructor that takes 0' arguments" when I try to set my constructor as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
abstract class Book
{

    protected String title;
    protected  String author;

    public Book(String t,String a){
        title=t;
        author=a;
    }
    public abstract void display();

}

class MyBook : Book
{
    private int price = 0;

    public MyBook(string t, string a, int p)
    {
            base.title = t;
            base.author = a;
            this.price = p;
    }

    public override void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Title: {title}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Author: {author}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Price: {price}");
    }
}
```

I've narrowed down the issue to how I am using the base keyword.  I should be using use a base constructor initializer, with the base keyword, in its constructor declaration.

```
    public MyBook(string t, string a, int p)
    : base(t, a) 
    {
            this.price = p;
    }
```

Will someone please explain to me why I cannot use base. in my constructor here?  Is it because title and author variables are both protected members of the abstract class?  I thought that since I'm deriving from Book, I have access to these protected members. Or is it because I haven't instantiated my subclass and thus I cannot set my constructor this way?

Comment: Because you have defined a base constructor that expects 2 arguments before it can initialize and serve you it's members.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You CAN use protected properties in the way you were trying to.  That's not the problem you're encountering.  When you try to create an instance of the derived class, the program needs to know which constructor of the base class to call to create that portion of the object.  If you don't specify, the default (no argument) constructor is called.  The base class doesn't have one of those, so you get the error.  `:base(t,a)` is necessary to tell it WHICH constructor to use, and what arguments to pass it.  If you wanted, you could do:

```
public MyBook(string t, string a, int p)
: base(t, a) 
{
        base.title = t;
        base.author = a;
        this.price = p;
}
```

Of course, in this example that would be silly, but you can see that it will let you use those properties in the way you were trying.

Answer (score 1):

If you write a class with no constructors, the compiler defines a parameterless default constructor for you, as a convenience for writing simple quickie classes.

When you start defining constructors explicitly, the compiler assumes that you are defining exactly the set of constructors that you want to have. This gives you control over how your class can be created, while preserving the convenience of writing simple classes that use the default constructor.

`MyBook` is a `Book`. Before `MyBook` can initialize itself, `Book` must first do so. But there's no parameterless constructor to be called here. `Book` has chosen, explicitly as far as the compiler is concerned, to *forbid* what you are doing here. The language assumes that if you wanted people -- subclasses, your aunt Sally, anybody -- to be able to create a `Book` with a parameterless constructor, you'd have provided one.

```
public MyBook(string t, string a, int p)
{
        base.title = t;
        base.author = a;
        this.price = p;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't just set the properties of the base class without calling the constructor. Because the base class has a constructor that takes arguments (and no default constructor) you must explicitly call the constructor of the base class.

```
public MyBook(string t, string a, int p)
    :base(t, a)
{
    this.price = p;
}
```

When you create an instance of the derived class, you are in effect creating an instance of the base class. If a class has constructors that require arguments and *doesn't* have a default constructor, then the only way to create it is to call one of those constructors.

If `Book` and `MyBook` were in the same assembly then you could add an `protected` default constructor that only inherited classes could call, like this:

```
protected Book() { }
```

But it's better *not* to do that. You put that constructor there for a reason, so you don't want anything "bypassing" that constructor - not even an inherited class.

For example, you might decide that a `Book` can't have a null `title` or `author`, so you put validation in the constructor to make sure they aren't null. It's a good thing for `MyBook` to call the base class constructor because now that validation always takes place.

Comment: Actually he can.. the ctor argument is just a language constraint that he missed.

Comment: He can set the properties of the base class. He can't *just* set the properties of the base class. (Yeah, I could make that clearer.)

Comment: Well, Your _just_ made you explain it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Though there are multiple ways to solve your issue. I will try to answer in a better design perspective rather just solve your problem.

If I'd to define such a class structure I would go about doing like this

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

abstract class Book
{
    protected String title;
    protected String author;

    public Book(String t, String a)
    {
        this.title = t;
        this.author = a;
    }

    public abstract void display();
}

class MyBook : Book
{
    private int price = 0;

    public MyBook(string t, string a, int p) : base(t, a) // Let the base class decide what it wants to do with these arguments
    {
        this.price = p;
    }

    public override void display()
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Title: {title}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Author: {author}");
        Console.WriteLine($"Price: {price}");
    }
}
```